# Macro Error in Line of COde

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that adds zeroes to every number in column a until there are 7 total digits in the number, it has worked fine up until today and I am getting an error in the line For1= i=1 To endrow = -1 and I cannot figure out what it means.

THe code is

```
Sub AddZeroes()
'Declarations
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, endrow As Long
'Converts the A column format to Text format
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
'finds the bottom most row
endrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
'selects the top cell in column A
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

'loop to move from cell to cell
For i = 1 To endrow - 1
                'Moves the cell down 1. Assumes there's a header row so really starts at row 2
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                'The Do-While loop keeps adding zeroes to the front of the cell value until it hits a length of 7
    Do While Len(ActiveCell.Value) < 7
                                ActiveCell.Value = "0" & ActiveCell.Value
                Loop
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Update your Integer declarations to Long, as iDevelop suggested. You might find this a better approach to get the end row: `endrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row`

Answer (score 2):

`i` has probably hit the high limit of an integer (32767). `Row` returns a `Long` so `i` should be a  `Long`, like `EndRow`

`Dim i As Long`

Comment: So how would I fix it? It has always worked the dozens of times I have used it up until now.

Comment: I tried it with just 10 rows and it still did it, I am trying to see the issue in the Immediate Window

Answer (score 0):

I re-wrote your code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim c As Range, rngTarget As Range
    Set rngTarget = Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
    rngTarget.NumberFormat = "@"
    For Each c In rngTarget
        c.Value = Left(c.Value & "0000000", 7)
    Next c
End Sub
```

Clearer and faster.